# Filtering Data from different sheets located in different columns matching two Conditions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

**Objective**
I'm trying to retrieve data from different sheets in my spreadsheet based on two conditions: Year = 2023 and Month = May. The goal is to have one formula that filters the data and displays the results in a consistent order (LINK, COMPANY, TITLE) when both conditions are met.

**Problem**
I've constructed a formula that works correctly for one of the data sets (Monoti), but it's not functioning as expected for the other two (Rumala and Arbito).

- For **Monoti**, it correctly returns three results.
- For **Arbito** it returns one result even though it should return none (no rows meet the two conditions)
- For **Rumala**, it returns one result but it isn't correct (as shown in the picture below, the data should be the second row but it comes from the first one).

[image: Rumala yields the wrong result]

**Goal**
I'm looking for guidance on how to modify the formula to correctly filter data from different sheets based on the specified conditions. I want to retrieve the relevant data and ensure it is displayed in a consistent order (LINK, COMPANY, TITLE) for each row where the conditions are satisfied. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

**Data Structure**
Each sheet has columns representing LINK, COMPANY, TITLE, Year, and Month, among others. The order of the columns may differ between sheets, but the required data (LINK, COMPANY, TITLE) is present in all sheets. Each column should have its own header but there should be only one table containing all data.

**My attempt:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/185CaPyHmg_dScbTCateG2HlmsBd85WDJnjx-_u49hnA/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I have used is

```
=QUERY(Rumala!A2:N, "SELECT N, J, D WHERE L='2020' AND M='May'", 1)
```

but it yields the wrong results. I have also tried using =SORT(FILTER) and REGEXMATCH but without any success.

```
=SORT(FILTER(Rumala!A2:N, (REGEXMATCH(Rumala!L2:L, "^2023$")) * (REGEXMATCH(Rumala!M2:M, "^May$"))), 1)
```

**Expected result**

- Column A (Company) - retrieves columns I, M, N from sheets Monoti, Arbito, Rumala respectively.
- Column B (Post) - retrieves columns B, I, J from sheets Monoti, Arbito, Rumala respectively.
- Column C (Link) - retrieves column A from all sheets.

[image]

Column

Comment: Exactly which columns do you need in result? Please put that to the post in forst to last order like `LINK, COMPANY, TITLE, OtherCol1, OtherCol2,OtherCol3......`

Comment: @Harun24hr I have updated the question as per your request. Hope it is more clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *one approach* you may test out:

```
=let(Σ,{"Company","Title","Title_URL","Year","Month"},
     Λ,reduce(Σ,{"Monoti","Arbito","Rumala"},lambda(a,c,{a;choosecols(indirect("'"&c&"'!A2:Z"),index(xmatch(Σ,indirect("'"&c&"'!A1:Z1"),,-1)))})),
     {"Company","Post","Link";filter(choosecols(Λ,1,2,3),choosecols(Λ,1)<>"",choosecols(Λ,4)=2023,choosecols(Λ,5)="May")})
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there, this seems to work really well, actually, thank you. However, I am not well versed in this function. How could I add a new reference sheet to do the same so that the formula retrieves information from more sheets? I have tried adding a new sheet after "Monoti","Arbito","Rumala" but I get an error. Any help would b emuch appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can just add the `new tab` names here in this list `{"Monoti","Arbito","Rumala"}` of the formula. as long as these title_headers `{"Company","Title","Title_URL","Year","Month"}` are present in these new tab(s) within the range of `A1:Z1` it should work out normal. If its still throwing an error then it needs to be looked into.

Comment: This works great. I think I got the hang of it. I appreciate the help.